# Криптография. Горизонтальная перестановка

Tags: криптография, перестановка

дано задание найти открытый текст по закрытому(горизонтальная перестановка). Уже несколько дней сижу, никак не получается. Может кто нибудь помочь с этим? Или знает какой нибудь сервис, программу?

Закрытый текст:

ЛИЕОМ ШМГАН ЫРНЬЧ ИИГЕО ОДПТЕ СЛЧМЬ ЗИТЫИ МОТИА НЛОШЕ СОТЗП ВИСПМ УНЕТО ИДИРЧ ЖКАЛС ЛМЫМШ ИАЫАМ ЧИКАК ЛТШСД ИОИТЛ РИГЬО ТЧЗЕИ ТПОМН ПШКЛМ ИИЫЗА ТТНЕЖ ТЛХЕО ОЕСЖИ РИАТУ ЬДМКМ ИШЛЬТ АЧЫЦ

32 буквы в алфавите(е=ё), без пробелов и знаков препинания. Длина ключа неизвестна :(

Comment: Здесь точно горизонтальная перестановка?

Comment: В том то и дело, что по заданию горизонтальная. Конечно, возможно возникло небольшое недоразумение и задание неправильное, но сомневаюсь.